# Attempting to get character from an input file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get characters from an input file but I can't really get it to work, anyone who could help me on this one? I apologize in advance for the formatting, it confused me.

`open_input_and_output_file` basically checks whether or not you can open the files and in OTP I'm attempting to get every single character from one file to the other. As I couldn't get it to work I first tried displaying those characters in the console application, but that is also not working.

Any help would be appreciated, I hope the information provided is enough.

```
    bool open_input_and_output_file(ifstream& infile, ofstream& outfile)
{
//Precondition: True
assert(true);
//Postcondition: Inputfile and outputfile have either been opened succesfully or you have been notified of it not opening succesfully.
string inputfile;
string outputfile;
cout<<"\nPlease enter an input-file name (no spaces): ";
cin>>inputfile;
cout<<"NOTE: Input-file name and output-file name can NOT be the same!"<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter an output-file name (no spaces): ";
cin>>outputfile;
if(inputfile != outputfile)
{
    cout<<"Input-file name and output-file name are not the same! Good job on reading!"<<endl;
    ifstream infile(inputfile.c_str());
    if(infile)
        cout<<"Input-file: "<<inputfile<<" was opened succesfully!"<<endl;
    if(!infile)
        cout<<"Inputfile: "<<inputfile<<" could not be opened!"<<endl;
    ofstream outfile(outputfile.c_str());
    if(outfile)
        cout<<"Output-file: "<<outputfile<<" was opened succesfully!"<<endl;
    if(!outfile)
        cout<<"Outputfile: "<<outputfile<<" could not be opened!"<<endl;
}

else
{
    cout<<"Input-file name and output-file name are the same!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Opening has failed!"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
void OTP(ifstream& infile, ofstream& outfile)
{
int choice;
char character;
unsigned int r;
srand(r);

cout<<"\nPlease enter 0 to encrypt or 1 to decrypt: ";
cin>>choice;
if(open_input_and_output_file(infile,outfile))
{
    infile.get(character);
    cout<<character;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the error is here

```
cout<<"Input-file name and output-file name are not the same! Good job on reading!"<<endl;
ifstream infile(inputfile.c_str());
```

should be

```
cout<<"Input-file name and output-file name are not the same! Good job on reading!"<<endl;
infile.open(inputfile.c_str());
```

You make the same mistake with outfile.

```
ofstream outfile(outputfile.c_str());
```

should be

```
outfile.open(outputfile.c_str());
```

You pass infile and outfile as parameters to your `open_input_and_output_file` function, but then you declare them *again* inside the function. So when you open the files you aren't using the streams that were passed to `open_input_and_output_file`, instead you are using streams that are local to that function. The streams passed to `open_input_and_output_file` stay closed.